# Is the Webcam Logitech Logitech C930-E plug and play with Ubuntu

Tags: logitech

My OS : Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa).
My Hardware : Intel I5 based PC.

I am currently using the webcam Logitech C310 with Ubuntu for my online meetings  which was plug and play.  I did not need to do anything. Cheese app detected it spontaneously with good video and audio and Google meet works perfectly. Voice and video is OK with the C310. I want to upgrade to the Logitech C930-E (currently sold in amazon) for better video and voice quality.  Are there any additional drivers required or is is the C930 plug and play as well?

Thanks.

My updates after buying and using c930e for a few days. The c930e is plug and play with ubuntu 20.04 as far as the basic features. The Cheese app and Google meet work instantly with no issues. The video is much clearer  and sharper  than the c310. Voice is OK.

But this camera offers advanced functions like pan tilt and zoom (PTZ) for which logitech provides software for MAC and windows only @ https://logitechdriversupport.com/logitech-webcam-c930e-software/

Does anybody know if an app is available for Ubuntu to access PTZ functions for the c930e ?
Thanks

Comment: That camera has been around for over six years and *should* work just fine with 20.04. A colleague has used one since 18.04 and I've yet to hear him complain about it ... unless he did so when I wasn't paying attention. Unfortunately, I do not have one here to test with to confirm whether a stock 20.04 installation will pick it up without fiddling.

Comment: That is good enough for me. I am buying it. If it works with 18.04 I feel it will work with 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry this is going to get closed: we do not accept hardware recommendations. Besides that for future questions you have: please so not put the answer into the question and create an answer, update and accept it so the system cleans it from the open questions queue.

Comment: ok. I see what you mean. Got it.